# jQuery chaining order

Tags: jquery

Doing jQuery crash course all fine so far but:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#p1").css("color", "red")
                        .slideUp(2000)
                        .slideDown(2000);
            });
        });

<p id="p1">jQuery is fun!!</p>
```

This works fine but when I add a "change to blue" instruction (`.css("color", "blue")`) as the last link in the chain, the text turns blue as soon as I click the button instead of after the other events. What am I missing?

```
$("#p1").css("color", "red")
    .slideUp(2000)
    .slideDown(2000)
    .css("color", "blue");
```

Comment: As noted in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/), you need to supply an "on complete" function if you want something to happen only when the animation is done.

Comment: OK guess I was thinking that chaining was more powerful than it is. I thought each method was accessed sequentially. slideUp and slideDown ARE used sequentially but otherwise it seems that chaining really is just a method of concatenating - or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Probably should read up on [fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), if you haven't already.

Comment: Yep probably but trying to fix a page and only need to know what I need to know now (if you see what I mean). Just trying to get a v basic knowledge of jQuery in the next hour. (And this became a HUGE (interesting) diversion)  :-). Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining itself doesn't guarantee order of execution, it only returns the previous jQuery context so that you'll be able to further work with it in a fluent way.

In your specific case, the invocation of `slideUp` and `slideDown` functions takes time to complete (because of their animated nature), but jQuery will not wait for them to finish before calling further (chained) methods.

You need to pass a **callback** instead:

```
$("#p1")
    .css("color", "red")
    .slideUp(2000, function() {
        $(this).slideDown(2000, function() {
            $(this).css("color", "blue");
        });
    });
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kx0dsgq2/)

Comment: Because the call to `slideDown` is now contained in a `function`, and that function would only run *after* the animation completed (2000ms)

Comment: Sorry no you misunderstand. In the ORIGNAL when simply chained they work fine. Had not noticed this but your answer is "wrong" in that the only thing not working was the color part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$("#p1").css("color", "red")
    .slideUp(2000)
    .slideDown(2000, function() {       //function()" will add a callback
        $(this).css("color", "blue");   //this code will only execute after slideDown() has completed
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">Hello</p>
```

This uses a [callback](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/), so that `#p1` only turns blue after the animation has completed

Comment: Thanks works perfect here but not when I edit so must be missing a semi colon or something. Thanks for explanation all clear now.

Comment: Joe OK will ask you this as you are more on point on this bit -  
But .... why do not the two slides happen at the same time??? @Haim above stuck them in two functions BUT they work fine when simply chained... which is odd.